# highlighting all rowspans within a table row using CSS only

Tags: css

Is there a way of getting the CSS to highlight the entire row, including the cells within the rowspans, rather than just the first line?

As you can see from the example, only the first line of the row is highlighted but not the other cells, this obviously looks quite messy, and I would rather be able to clear it up using CSS only, but will use Javascript if there is no other way.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jErMee

HTML

```
<table class="tb" style="width: 100%;" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Package</td>

      <td>Includes</td>

      <td>Number of recruits</td>

      <td>Cost per recruit + VAT</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>

      <td rowspan="4">Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi.</td>

      <td>20+</td>

      <td>£105</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>10–19</td>

      <td>£120</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>6–9</td>

      <td>£135</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>1–5</td>

      <td>£150</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>

      <td rowspan="4">Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi.</td>

      <td>20+</td>

      <td>£175</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>10–19</td>

      <td>£200</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>6–9</td>

      <td>£225</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>1–5</td>

      <td>£250</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>

      <td rowspan="2">Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi.</td>

      <td>20+</td>

      <td>£220 (40% payable upfront)</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>10–19</td>

      <td>£275 (40% payable upfront)</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>

      <td rowspan="2">Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi.</td>

      <td>20+</td>

      <td>£300 (40% payable upfront)</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>10–19</td>

      <td>£375 (40% payable upfront)</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>

      <td>Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi.</td>

      <td><br /></td>

      <td><br /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
   padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}


tr:hover td {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Since the other values are inside his own `tr` the selector `tr:hover td` wouldn't target all...I think the best will be change yor markup and use inside tables.

Comment: I didn't know if exist some solution for this, but i recommend to insert another table inside last cell. this is my opinion, but if someone can solve this, I'm interested to see result

Comment: Or use Javascript // Jquery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [There is a JSBin.](http://jsbin.com/yabepe/1/edit?html,css,output)

I omit your part code, just for easily display.

The key of the issue is about `<tbody>`. A table must have a `<thead>`,but can have many `<tbody>`.
So, use these code:

```
tbody:hover .td {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Good option - might as well markup the headings with `<thead>` and `<th>` as well @GFo

Comment: This is a good solution, but if you had more than two rows, you would need a different css class for each one, correct?

Comment: @Marventus just modify HTML structure like this `<tbody>...</tbody>` and add CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I am updating my answer based on my comment to Todd Mark's answer. As mentioned above, and AFAICT, that solution would only work if the table has two main rows, but not if it has more.
For more than two main rows, I don't see any other way of doing it without JS. Indeed, I can think of two ways to do this:

## Way 1 (HTML & jQuery):

You can add a distinct css class to each main row in the HTML manually, like so:

### HTML:

```
<table class="tb" style="width: 100%;" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
    <thead>
        <th>Package</th>
        <th>Includes</th>
        <th>Number of recruits</th>
        <th>Cost per recruit + VAT</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="row-1">
            <td rowspan="4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td rowspan="4">Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi.</td>
            <td>20+</td>
            <td>£105</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-1">
            <td>10–19</td>
            <td>£120</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-1">
            <td>6–9</td>
            <td>£135</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-1">
            <td>1–5</td>
            <td>£150</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-2">
            <td rowspan="4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td rowspan="4">Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi.</td>
            <td>20+</td>
            <td>£175</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-2">
            <td>10–19</td>
            <td>£200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-2">
            <td>6–9</td>
            <td>£225</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-2">
            <td>1–5</td>
            <td>£250</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-3">
            <td rowspan="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td rowspan="2">Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi.</td>
            <td>20+</td>
            <td>£220 (40% payable upfront)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-3">
            <td>10–19</td>
            <td>£275 (40% payable upfront)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-4">
            <td rowspan="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td rowspan="2">Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi.</td>
            <td>20+</td>
            <td>£300 (40% payable upfront)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-4">
            <td>10–19</td>
            <td>£375 (40% payable upfront)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-5">
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi.</td>
            <td>
                <br />
            </td>
            <td>
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and use the following jQuery code for the hover effect:

### jQuery:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var tableRowClasses = function (sel) {
        sel = $(sel);
        $.each(sel, function (i, v) {
            // Bind hover event handler
            $(v).hover(function () {
                var ta = "." + $(v).attr("class");
                $(".hover").removeClass("hover");
                $(ta).addClass("hover");
            });
        });
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {
        tableRowClasses(".tb tr");
    });
});
```

### JSFiddle:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Marventus/qwvnqqdp/) for reference.

## Way 2 (jQuery only):

Or, you could add the css classes to each row dynamically using a pure jQuery approach:

### HTML:

```
<table class="tb" style="width: 100%;" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Package</td>
            <td>Includes</td>
            <td>Number of recruits</td>
            <td>Cost per recruit + VAT</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td rowspan="4">Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi.</td>
            <td>20+</td>
            <td>£105</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>10–19</td>
            <td>£120</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6–9</td>
            <td>£135</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1–5</td>
            <td>£150</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td rowspan="4">Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi.</td>
            <td>20+</td>
            <td>£175</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>10–19</td>
            <td>£200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6–9</td>
            <td>£225</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1–5</td>
            <td>£250</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td rowspan="2">Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi.</td>
            <td>20+</td>
            <td>£220 (40% payable upfront)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>10–19</td>
            <td>£275 (40% payable upfront)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td rowspan="2">Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi.</td>
            <td>20+</td>
            <td>£300 (40% payable upfront)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>10–19</td>
            <td>£375 (40% payable upfront)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi.</td>
            <td>
                <br />
            </td>
            <td>
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### jQuery:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var tableRowClasses = function (sel) {
        var num = 0;
        sel = $(sel);
        $.each(sel, function (i, v) {
            // Bind hover event handler
            $(v).hover(function () {
                var ta = "." + $(v).attr("class");
                $(".hover").removeClass("hover");
                $(ta).addClass("hover");
            });
            // Add row classes
            var hasClass = typeof $(v).attr("class") !== "undefined";
            if (hasClass && $(v).attr("class").search(/row/) > -1) return true;
            else {
                var css = "row-" + num;
                $(v).addClass(css);
                if ($(v).find("td[rowspan]").length > 0) {
                    var rowS = parseInt($($(v).find("td[rowspan]")[0]).attr("rowspan"), 10),
                        start = $.inArray(v, sel);
                    for (i = start; i < start + rowS; i++) {
                        $(sel[i]).addClass(css);
                    }
                }
                num++;
            }
        });
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {
        tableRowClasses(".tb tr");
    });
});
```

### JSFiddle:

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Marventus/ytaxscur/) for reference.

## In both cases:

You would need the following css code for each solution to work:

### CSS:

```
.hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
```