# How to shade every other table row that spans across multiple rows?

Tags: html, css, tabular

I am trying to shade every other row that spans across multiple rows next to it while also shading those rows (not each). How would I do this with just CSS if it is possibly at all?

```
----------------------------------------------
| HEADER | HEADER | HEADER | HEADER | HEADER | 
----------------------------------------------
|        | COLUMN | COLUMN | COLUMN | COLUMN | 
| COLUMN |------------------------------------
|        | COLUMN | COLUMN | COLUMN | COLUMN | 
----------------------------------------------
|        | COLUMN | COLUMN | COLUMN | COLUMN | 
|        |------------------------------------
| COLUMN | COLUMN | COLUMN | COLUMN | COLUMN | 
| shaded |------------------------------------
|        | COLUMN | COLUMN | COLUMN | COLUMN | 
----------------------------------------------
| COLUMN | COLUMN | COLUMN | COLUMN | COLUMN | 
----------------------------------------------
|        | COLUMN | COLUMN | COLUMN | COLUMN | 
| COLUMN |------------------------------------
| shaded | COLUMN | COLUMN | COLUMN | COLUMN | 
----------------------------------------------
```

In case it wasn't clear, the rows next to shaded rowspan should be shaded all together as well.

Comment: And your code and try is?

Comment: When you say shade, what do you really mean?

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/27528420/2887133

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want the shading to be based on cells with a `rowspan`, `nth-child` on `tr` won't work in this situation.

Instead, you can place each section of rows inside a `tbody` element, and apply `nth-child` styling to that tag:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 0.3em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

tbody:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #def;
}

tbody {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td> HEADER <td> HEADER <td> HEADER <td> HEADER <td> HEADER </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td rowspan="2">COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN 
    <tr>                       <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN 
  </tbody>

  <tbody>
    <tr><td rowspan="3">COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN 
    <tr>                       <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN 
    <tr>                       <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN 
  </tbody>

  <tbody>
    <tr><td rowspan="1">COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN 
  </tbody>

  <tbody>
    <tr><td rowspan="2">COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN 
    <tr>                       <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

An alternative is to use jQuery to shade the cells.

The code below looks at the first `td` of each row.  If its `offsetLeft` is 0, it's the first cell in its column, and that's what we want to base the shading on.

If it's an odd-numbered cell, we shade its parent `tr` and its parent `tr`'s next `x` siblings, where `x` is based on the number of rows that the cell spans:

```
var odd= true;
$('tr td:first-child').each(function() {
  if(!this.offsetLeft) {
    if(odd) {
      $(this).parent('tr').nextAll().addBack().slice(0, this.rowSpan).css('background','yellow');
    }
    odd= !odd;
  }    
});
```

```js
var odd= true;
$('tr td:first-child').each(function() {
  if(!this.offsetLeft) {
    if(odd) {
      $(this).parent('tr').nextAll().addBack().slice(0, this.rowSpan).css('background','yellow');
    }
    odd= !odd;
  }    
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 0.3em;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td> HEADER <td> HEADER <td> HEADER <td> HEADER <td> HEADER 
  <tr><td rowspan="2">COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN 
  <tr>                       <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN 

  <tr><td rowspan="3">COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN 
  <tr>                       <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN 
  <tr>                       <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN 

  <tr><td rowspan="1">COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN 

  <tr><td rowspan="2">COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN 
  <tr>                       <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN <td> COLUMN 
</table>
```

Comment: In your first code snippet, something like `tbody:nth-child(odd) tr:first-child td:first-child { background-color: #def; }` would shade just the first column of the first row, which appears to be the op's intent.

Comment: That would certainly shade the first column only, but I think the OP wants the other cells shaded based on his comment, "the rows next to shaded rowspan should be shaded all together as well."

Comment: Ah, right. Was looking at the picture, not the words. ;-)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, and now I feel ashamed for not thinking of this... Thank you

Comment: Is there another tag that can be used instead of tbody? tbody doesn't support few css properties like border.

Comment: If the table has `border-collapse` and the `tbody` border is at least 2px, it works.  I've updated my first Snippet.

Answer (score 2):

is this what youre looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/33/

use the nth-child(even), or odd depending on preference and set a background color.

```
table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:lightgray;
}

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td>stuff here</td>
        <td>stuff here</td>
        <td>stuff here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>stuff here</td>
        <td>stuff here</td>
        <td>stuff here</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```